# How to load <script type=module> in AJAX?

Tags: javascript, ajax, module

How can I load the module script via jQuery AJAX? I like to load PhotoSwipe via AJAX because my gallery depends on the user's input.

```
<script type="module">
import PhotoSwipeLightbox from 'photoswipe/dist/photoswipe-lightbox.esm.js';
const lightbox = new PhotoSwipeLightbox({
  gallery: '#my-gallery',
  children: 'a',
  pswpModule: () => import('photoswipe/dist/photoswipe.esm.js')
});
lightbox.init();
</script>
```

We have a HTML form. After user submits the form, the server will return the content and jQuery will insert the response into the DOM. The response is stored and displayed inside a div.

```
$('#form').ajaxForm({ 
        target: '#feedbackSection',
        url: 'server.php',
        type: 'post',
        beforeSubmit: beforeSubmit,
        success: showResponse
    });
```

Typically, I include some JavaScript codes in the response code. I've noticed that the type=module is not loaded:

```
<script type='module'>
    //This code is not loaded.
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  //This code is loaded.

});
</script>
```

Is there any way I can fix this issue? Thanks.

Comment: no `<script>` tags retrieved using AJAX are "exectued" - it's nothing specific about module types

Comment: Are you sure? The codes in the <script type="text/javascript"> are executed.

Comment: Oh, that may be jqueery doing something - how are you currently adding the response to the DOM?

Comment: via jQuery Form. User submits the form data, the server side returns both HTML and JavaScript code. Browser puts the responses into a div (like a placeholder). For some odd reasons, only the <script type="text/javascript"> got loaded. <script type='module'> is ignored.

Comment: if you used XMLHttpRequest or fetch, then no scripts would be parsed - jqueery handles scripts for you, but only `type="text/javascript"` it seems - maybe you have to go through the scripts you just added to the DOM, and re-add them - however, I'm not sure it will work with `type="module"` - I've never tried - but, hey, you can try

Comment: @DerrickC. Ever find a solution?

Comment: No I haven't. I ended up switching to the older version of PhotoSwipe, which is more jQuery friendly.

Comment: Same issue here, need it to work with AJAX

Answer (score 2):

This is [a bug of jQuery](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/issues/3871).

Updating jQuery version to 3.3.0+ should solve the issue.